# Restrict users from changing their Primary DNS server while connected to my Wi-Fi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

Is there a way to prevent users to change their DNS server while connected to my Wi-Fi connection? As far as I know, they can change their DNS server (e.g. 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, etc.) on the Wi-Fi settings of their devices. I am strictly logging DNS queries 'cause I have young cousins in our house and I don't want them to visit porn websites using my Wi-Fi connection.

I am using `AdGuard Home` to block those kinds of websites. I hosted it in the cloud to act as a public DNS server.

While using LTE, I can't change the Primary and Secondary DNS server. Are there any workarounds to bring this to Wi-Fi?

Comment: You're not going to be able to force a DNS server on devices you don't have Administrative control over, even if you do it at the router level a user could simply change their DNS provider to NOT be your router.  Any control you attempt can also be bypassed by using a VPN or a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

you can' do it at Wifi configuration level, because it would suppose that Wifi have control of the clients machines, which is not the case.

What you can do is filter at the gateway level, capturing DNS query and redirecting to your controlled DNS, so even if they change DNS nameservers they would still get filtered. So you need firewall control of your internet gateway.

Be carefull because that do not include DNS over HTTPS, nor VPN or exfiltrating tools like Tor or VPN over DNS, but it would be challenging for Kids to get out.